# Access all the form data in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code

```
<form method="POST">
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="c in controls">
<label ng-if="c.type == 2">{{c.value}}</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-if="c.type == 3" name="field_{{c.id}}" placeholder="{{c.label}}" pattern="{{c.regex}}" value="{{c.defaultValue}}" />

 <nvd3-pie-chart ng-if="pieChart" data="pieChartData" id="pieChartExample" height="350" showlabels="true" interactive="true" x="xPieFunction()" y="yPieFunction()"><svg height="250"></svg></nvd3-pie-chart>

<div ng-if="c.type == 5">
<label>{{ c.label }}</label>
<div ng-repeat="chk in c.options">
<input type="checkbox" name="field_{{c.id}}" value="defaultValues[$index]"  /> {{chk.name}} <br/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
                                    <p>&nbsp;</p>

<button ng-click="back()" ng-if="$index != 0" class="btn btn-primary pull-left">Back</button>
<button ng-if="canContinue" ng-click="submit()" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Next</button>
```

Some of the elements are dynamically used depending upon the requirement. For example in some cases only the text input will be visible while at some cases both text and checkbox and few additional inputs will be visible. The name atribute of these form elements also varies as you can see it is set from the data which is passed to the form

example

Scenario 1

input id = 4
input name = field_4

Scenario 2

input id = 1
input name = field_1

I have this function in my controller

`$scope.submit = function(){                };`

Here i want to get all the posted data. Currently as per what i have searched and understood i need to specify the ng-model attribute and then use $scope to get the data but due to the limitations i.e the dynamic naming i'm unsure how to do this.

Comment: You need to get help from angular site before posting to SO.

Comment: http://tutsnare.com/post-form-data-using-angularjs/ maybe this helps but google is your friend